# ImportError: No module named generator

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

```
 File "./home/quickstart.py", line 2, in <module>
        import httplib2
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
        import email
      File "/home/sushant/home/email.py", line 7, in <module>
        from apiclient import discovery
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        from googleapiclient import discovery
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 41, in <module>
        from email.generator import Generator as BytesGenerator
    ImportError: No module named generator
```

Using google-api-python-client and getting this error . Please Help !!!

Answer (score 5):

You have a local file called "email.py" which is hiding the stdlib module. Rename your file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked !!